# using a 2d array in a java api when the api will be invoked from a javascript client

Tags: java, javascript, api, cxf

I am working to create a simple API in Java using Apache CXF- in one function of the API, one of the inputs is required to be a 2-d array.

This API will be invoked from a javascript client.

I am confused about the following--

(a) I dont want to restrict the size of the 2-d array parameter in the Java function. What should be the type of this parameter- should I use an arraylist? Or something else? Can you give a sample declaration for the java portion of the 2d array?

(b) When the javascript client makes a call to the API, it will send data in the 2d array. Now, sometimes the data will be only a single dimensional array, while other times it will be a 2-d array...Also the size of each dimension will also differ in various calls to this function from the javascript client. Now, after the Java API has received a function call, how do I process the data contained within the 2d javascript array?

(c) Is there any restriction/rule that I should keep in mind while sending the 2d data from the Javascript client?

Answer (score 0):

Neither language has a 2-d array type.  Both handle this sort of data with arrays of arrays.  As to the type parameters in Java, just use the double-square bracket notation, `MyType[][]`, which represents an array of arrays of objects of `MyType`.

When you say that sometimes the data will be a 1-d array, how will you handle it in Java, or is it simply that you will have an array of 1-d arrays?

Processing the data in Javascript should be simple enough, just a nested loop.  But since neither language will enforce the constraints that each row has columns of the same length, you might have to do something additional if you're requiring rectangular 2-d arrays.

And no, there are no particular restrictions for your 2d data going into Javascript, nothing more than you already have for converting other Java data to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a list of lists and not an array of arrays.
2. If the client sends two different formats of data, you need two different methods, you can't handle 1D array and 2D array with the same method
3. On the java side use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to serialize/de-serialize the json objects